# Snowblower blades hitting sides

Tags: snow

One side of my snow-blower got caught in a rope and snapped both shear pins (for that side).
I found two spare pins that came with it and installed them.

But when I turned the machine back on the blades on that side started hitting the side of the machine. I'm afraid to use it in this state I think I might break it more. Is there an easy way to fix this?[image]

Now that I'm looking at this picture I can see that the blade is bent. What can I use to bend it back?

Comment: Sounds like something is bent.  A photo might help.

Comment: Turn blades by hand and check on both ends.  Think you will find one or more blades on problem side are bent out some.  Should bend problem blade/s back towards centre.  Should not require more than a long bar and gentle pushing back.

Comment: Probably it's bent (rope will do that) - one other slight possibility is that there *might* be more than one set of shear pin holes, and you might have inadvertently moved it outward by using a set closer to the end being hit. But it's probably just bent, and needs to be bent back.

Comment: It's also possible that the bearing at the side that scrapes has been damaged or the shaft has been knocked out of the bearing. Inspect and see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have had good luck using a crescent wrench when needing to bend “thin metal” close the jaws tight then the cresent wrench gives some leverage. The larger the wrench the more leverage large water pipe adjustable pliers would be another tool I would use

Comment: Right. The exact shape of the auger blades isn't critical. Go ahead and flex them away from the housing. Rotate the auger to get the troublesome portion to the front first.

Comment: So ... a regular adjustable wrench?  like this one https://www.stanleytools.com/products/automotive-tools/wrenches/adjustable-wrenches/10-in-adjustable-wrench/87-471 ?

Comment: Yes the larger it is the more leverage you will have. I know you may think those blades are thick but with a little leverage they will bend fairly easily

Comment: You could also use locking pliers (Vice-Grip™ is one brand name) to get hold of the metal to bend it. They make those in a variety of sizes, too.